# Nikud in MySQL giving question marks

Tags: mysql, hebrew

I have a classic ASP script using MySQL 5.6. I'm trying to insert Hebrew *nikud* characters into the database. The source encoding is `windows-1255`, and when I output the query to the screen, it outputs the *nikud* properly. However, when I try to insert the text into the DB, the Hebrew letters go in fine, while the *nikud* turns into question marks.

I have tried running `SET NAMES 'hebrew'`, and changing the collation of the relevant table to hebrew_bin, hebrew_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci, all surprisingly with the same result.

Running the same query in PHPMyAdmin also resulted in question marks in place of *nikud*, so the problem isn't with the script but with the DB.

What am I doing wrong and what settings should the DB have to accept *nikud*?

Comment: Maybe someone can still answer, but just to clarify I can't test this anymore. The solution at the time was to convert the whole project to unicode, it took weeks but we had no other choice.